# How to extract Image Info from Image in ImageMagick Core

Tags: c, imagemagick

I think it's very easy, but can't find how in the documentation or by Googling it.

I and interested in only low level MagicCore not MagicWand.

Answer (score 0):

The `Image` structure has a property `image_info` that points to the `ImageInfo` used during `ReadImage`.

To extract the `ImageInfo`, use `CloneImageInfo`.

```c
ImageInfo * myInfo;
myInfo = CloneImageInfo(myImage->image_info);
if (myInfo == (ImageInfo *)NULL) { // Error handle
```

Comment: What? No https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/image.h#L151